# Python 3 high score label displays 0 instead of showing value from Pickle

Tags: python, pygame

I know I just asked another question earlier, but I'm kinda stuck. My game is about you moving between three spaces to dodge squares of different speeds. The "speed" text label (I don't know what to call it) updates fine (and it updates when a block reaches the bottom of the screen) but the high score text label (which the high score is loaded from the pickle). And if you're wondering there already is a high score loaded in the pickle file. It's not empty.

```
import pygame
import random
import math
import sys
import cPickle as pickle
#import os.path

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

score = 0

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)

screenWidth = 700
screenHeight = 800

red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)
cyan = (0,255,255)
purple = (255, 0, 255)

x = screenWidth / 2
y = (screenHeight / 4) * 3
width = 50
height = 50
highScore = 0


corn1 = pygame.image.load("new1.png")
corn2 = pygame.image.load("new2.png")
corn3 = pygame.image.load("new3.png")
corn4 = pygame.image.load("new4.png")

mac = [corn1, corn2, corn3, corn4]

class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.walkCount = 0

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 60:
            self.walkCount = 0
        win.blit(mac[self.walkCount//15], (self.x,self.y))
        self.walkCount += 1


win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Corn Dash")

bg = pygame.image.load("background.png").convert()
gameover = pygame.image.load("gameover.png").convert()
#corn = pygame.image.load("player.png")
bgx = (screenWidth / 6) * 2
bgy = 0



#mac = [pygame.image.load("1.png"), pygame.image.load("2.png"), pygame.image.load("3.png"), pygame.image.load("4.png")]

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class enemy():
    def __init__(self,c,y,width,height, color, vel):
        self.c = c
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = vel
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, win):
        global score
        if gameOver == False:
            if self.c == 1:
                self.x = 250
                #250
            elif self.c == 2:
                self.x = 350
                #350
            else:
                self.x = 450
                #450
            self.y += self.vel
            if self.y >= 800:
                score += 1
                self.y = random.randint(-500,0)
                self.c = random.randint(1,3)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (self.color), (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height))
        else:
            self.y = 0

evil = enemy(random.randint(1,3),0,50,50, blue, 5)
evil2 = enemy(random.randint(1,3),-400,50,50, blue, 5)
evil3 = enemy(random.randint(1,3),random.randint(-500,-100),50,50, blue, 5)
evil4 = enemy(random.randint(1,3),-1000,50,50, yellow, 15)
evil5 = enemy(random.randint(1,3),100,50,50, purple, 2)

running = True
gameOver = False

corn = player(screenWidth/2,(screenHeight / 4) * 3)

def saveScore():
    highScore = score
    pickle_out = open("save.pickle","wb")
    pickle.dump(highScore, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()
    print("Score saved:" + str(highScore))

def  loadScore():
    pickle_in = open("save.pickle","rb")
    highScore = pickle.load(pickle_in)
    pickle_in.close()
    print("Score loaded:" + str(highScore))

loadScore()
while running:
    # -----The game over scene.-----
    while gameOver:
        scoreLabel = myfont.render(("Score:"+str(score)), False, (0,0,0))
        highScoreLabel = myfont.render(("High Score:"+str(highScore)), False, (0,0,0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                # pygame.quit only uninitializes the pygame modules and
                # doesn't quit the program.
                pygame.quit()
                # This will quit the whole program. You need to import sys.
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:  # event.type not pygame.event.type
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    # Change it to False to break out of the loop.
                    gameOver = False
                    # Reset the game. You could reset the position of the
                    # `evil` object or instantiate a new one.
                    x = 350
                    evil.c = random.randint(1,3)
                    evil.y = 0
                    evil2.c = random.randint(1,3)
                    evil2.y = random.randint(-300,0)
                    evil3.c = random.randint(1,3)
                    evil3.y = random.randint(-600,20)
                    evil4.c = random.randint(1,3)
                    evil4.y = random.randint(-3000,-2500)
                    evil5.c = random.randint(1,3)
                    evil5.y = random.randint(0,300)
                    score = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    saveScore()
                    print("Score saved:"+str(highScore))

        highScoreLabel = myfont.render(("High Score:"+str(highScore)), False, (0,0,0))
        win.blit(gameover, (0,0))
        win.blit(scoreLabel,(0,0))
        win.blit(highScoreLabel, (0,30))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)  # You need to call tick in this loop as well.

    # ------------------------------
    # -----The main scene.-----
    highScoreLabel1 = myfont.render(("High Score:"+str(highScore)), False, (255,255,255))
    scoreLabel1 = myfont.render(("Score:"+str(score)), False, (255,255,255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and corn.x < 450:
                corn.x += 100
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and corn.x > 250:
                corn.x -= 100

    win.fill((0,0,0))
    win.blit(bg, (bgx, bgy))
    evil.draw(win)
    evil2.draw(win)
    evil3.draw(win)
    evil4.draw(win)
    evil5.draw(win)
    win.blit(scoreLabel1,(0,0))
    win.blit(highScoreLabel1, (0,30))
    dist = math.hypot(evil.x - corn.x, evil.y - corn.y)
    dist2 = math.hypot(evil2.x - corn.x, evil2.y - corn.y)
    dist3 = math.hypot(evil3.x - corn.x, evil3.y - corn.y)
    dist4 = math.hypot(evil4.x - corn.x, evil4.y - corn.y)
    dist5 = math.hypot(evil5.x - corn.x, evil5.y - corn.y)
    if dist <= 50 or dist2 <= 50 or dist3 <= 50 or dist4 <= 50 or dist5 <= 50:
        print("Game Over!")
        gameOver = True
    corn.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Do you have any debug output? This is just a guess, but it seems to me that perhaps your `score` variable is not incrementing. I notice `saveScore()` assigns `highScore = score` regardless of what `score` is. Should this only happen if `score > highScore`? I see you define `highScore` at the top in an outer scope, so you're *probably* okay there, but you might want to double-check that variable is being modified where you think it is, and it's not another variable of the same name in a different namespace that is being worked on. I'm not sure on that one TBH.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variable scope issue. While you defined both `score` and `highScore` as global variables (outside of any function) you then assign a value to `highScore` in both `saveScore()` and `loadScore()`. When you perform an assignment, Python will interpret the variable as **local to the function** . The net result for `saveScore()` is still working. In fact, you could assign `score` a value and see it saved correctly. But when you use `loadScore()`, the value is read from the file, then assigned to `highScore`, but only in **local scope of the function**: once the function is done, the value is lost.

Two ways to fix this.

The simplest would be to simply add a `global highScore` statement inside the `loadScore()` function, so that there is no ambiguity. This works, but is not really recommended.

The second, and most appropriate way to do this, would be to restructure a bit your variable scope, and make changes like:

1. Have `saveScore()` accept a parameter, which is the value you want to save
2. Have `loadScore()` return the loaded value in a `return` statement
3. keep track of `score` and `highScore` inside the main loop, and save/load when appropriate

Also, for a better and more complete explanation, check out this tutorial on [Global, Local and nonlocal Variables](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php) . Hope this helps.